# Load an do operations with a matrix whose name varies within a Matlab loop

Tags: matlab

I have to run a Matlab loop indexed by `x`. At each iteration, I have to load and work with an array, `A_x.mat`, where the subscript `x` follows the loop index. How can I do that? Let me give you and example to highlight my issue. The example is very silly but serves my purposes.

```
X=10;
C=cell(X,1)
for x=1:X
    load(['A_' num2str(x) '.mat']); %here I load A_x.mat
    %C{x}=A_x*3;
end
```

I don't know how to compute `A_x*3` in a way that allows the subscript `x` to vary. Could you advise?

---

To solve my issue I also tried

```
   for x=1:X
        B=load(['A_' num2str(x) '.mat']); %here I load A_x.mat and "rename" it B
        %C{x}=B*3;
    end
```

but `B` turns out to be a `1x1` struct with 1 field that is again `A_x`. Hence, I have not solved anything.

Comment: You can do `B.(name)`, where `name` is an expression that evaluates to a string. For example in your case `B.(['A_' num2str(x)])`. Also look up `fieldnames`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the structure subfield name as a char and access the structure with it directly:

```
X=10;
C=cell(X,1)
for x=1:X
    name = ['A_', num2str(x)];
    data_structure = load([name, '.mat']); %here I load A_x.mat
    C{x} = data_structure.(name) * 3;
end
```

Note that you could achieve something similar with eval() but that is not recommended. If ever you need to access variables dynamically like this, use a structure.